# is there any option like "removeClippedSubviews" in angular 8 or reactjs which optimizes the heavy content of web components?

Tags: angular, reactjs

i'm making a web app which has a very heavy page i need an option like "removeClippedSubviews" in react native which optimizes the heavy list in order not to loss performance and lag ...

have your something similar in reactjs or angular ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Angular Material, and your list items have the same size, you can use [virtual scrolling](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview#virtual-scrolling) to achieve that:

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="50">
  <div *cdkVirtualFor="let item of items">{{item}}</div>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

You can check [this complete example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/jxrpmdqypyk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-virtual-scroll-overview-example.ts) with a list of 100000 items.

If the list items' size is not always the same, or your scrolling scenario is more complex, you will need to implement your own [`VirtualScrollStrategy`](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/api#VirtualScrollStrategy).